# Get values from .exe (converted from .py) entry field and use these values in another .py file

Tags: python

I have a `GUI.exe` (converted from a `.py` file) that has entry boxes.

I want to get the values that was entered in entry boxes from this `GUI.exe` and use it in a Python file (`.py`).

Is that possible? Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  What have you tried so far?  Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a csv by doing

```
import csv 
with open('GUI_data.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(all_data)              #all_data should be list of all data
```

With the other file you could do this to load data out as a list

```
with open('GUI_data.csv', newline='') as file:
    file_data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    transfered_data = next(file_data)       # transfered_data now holds the info as a list
```